# Adding additional options to select using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Im trying to add additional options to a dropdownlist using ajax in JQM. The first option is a static disabled selected and hidden option. The other options are extracted from a webservice using ajax. The dropdownlist itself is inside a popup window.

This is my code:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="puIceCream"><div>
     <center>Select Flavor:</center>
     <select id="ddlFlavorsIC">
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
         <!--Flavors are added here-->
     </select>
</div>
```

And the JS code is below:

```
$("#puIceCream").on("popupafteropen", function (event) {
    if (!$("#ddlFlavorsIC option").length) {
        WebServiceURL = "IceWS.asmx";
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: WebServiceURL + "/GetFlavors",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "get",
            data: "{ }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function (err) {
                alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var size = data["d"].length;
                for (var i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
                    $("#ddlFlavorsIC").append("<option>" + ((String)(data["d"][i].value)) + "</option>");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If I remove the static hidden option on the markup it works fine, but for some reason it doesn't work with it. why is that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (!$("#ddlFlavorsIC option").length) {
```

to

```
if ($("#ddlFlavorsIC option").length < 2){
```

Your code only adds flavors if there are zero options in the dropdown, so your one static option causes you not to enter the IF statement.

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/QEoZNZ)**

Comment: oh wow, can't believe I didn't notice that! Thanks for your help!